# Java Post Connection Using Try with Resources

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, try-with-resources

I want to implement the code for handling POST requests using try with resources.

Following is my code:

```
public static String sendPostRequestDummy(String url, String queryString) {
    log.info("Sending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    log.info("Data : " + queryString);
    BufferedReader in = null;
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    try{
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        // add request header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(queryString);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        log.info("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        if (responseCode >= 400)
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream()));
        else 
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        log.error("Error during posting request");
    }
    finally{
        closeConnectionNoException(in,con);
    }
    return response.toString();
}
```

I have the following concerns for the code:

1. How to introduce conditional statements in try with resources for the above scenario?
2. Is there a way to pass on the connection in try with resources? (It can be done using nested try-catch blocks since URL and HTTPConnection is not AutoCloseable, which itself is not a compliant solution)
3. Is using try with resources for the above problem is a better approach?

Answer (score 17):

Try this.

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
try (AutoCloseable conc = () -> con.disconnect()) {
    // add request headers
    try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream())) {
        wr.writeBytes(queryString);
    }
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    try (InputStream ins = responseCode >= 400 ? con.getErrorStream() : con.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins))) {
        // receive response
    }
}
```

`() -> con.disconnect()` is a lambda expression which execute `con.disconnect()` at finally stage of the try statement.

Comment: That's fine for most of my queries. But, is using nested try a good approach? I mean my code is working fine with try-catch-finally. What is the advantage of this approach?

Comment: @Chinmayjain If you/someone copy-pastes the code, it will appear as one monolithic block.

Comment: The advantage is in reliability. Any close can cause IOException. You can also move the code to private methods (ie writeQuery and readResponse), so it would look better ;)

Answer (score 3):

HttpURLConnection does not implement the AutoCloseable interface in Java 8 or later versions.
Since HttpURLConnection does not implement AutoCloseable, you cannot use it directly in a try-with-resources block. However, you can create a wrapper class that implements AutoCloseable and encapsulates the HttpURLConnection object, and then use the wrapper class in a try-with-resources block.

[Click here to check further details](https://ctcsinfo.blogspot.com/2023/05/right-way-to-close-httpsurlconnetion.html)

Answer (score 0):

1: You can use conditional statements inside `try` with resources statement also. Unfortunately you have to define new variable for this block and cannot use a predefined variable. ( variable `in` in your code)

```
try (BufferedReader in = (responseCode >= 400 ? new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream())) : new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())))) {
   // your code for getting string data
}
```

2: I'm not sure `HttpUrlConnection` is `AutoCloseable`, So it might be a good idea to call the `disconnect()` yourself. I'm open to any suggestion on this one.

3: `try` with resources will definitely help you in managing the resources. But if you're confident that you're releasing the resources properly after use, then your code is fine.